# SelectionChangedCommited functionality in Combobox (XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox

In the example below, when i try to set values to the *combobox*, the event is triggered and change *objRunSettings*.xxx before the value is set to *cmbxxx.SelectedValue*.

I suppose i need something like SelectionChangedCommited instead of SelectionChanged but i am really confused how to do it, as in xaml my only option is *SelectionChanged*

In xaml

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged ="cmbxxx_selectionChanged"/>
```

In .cs -> set combobox values

```
cmbxxx.SelectedValue = objRunSettings.xxx;
```

Event

```
private void cmbxxx_selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    objRunSettings.xxx = cmbxxx.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in the e.AddedItems IList will be the value you are looking for.

[MSDN SelectionChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)